# Interface implementation fails for generic type, because of "does not have the matching return type" error

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a class:

```
 public abstract class Structure<T, S> : IStructure
    where T : StructureModel<S>, new()
    where S : StructureStats, new()
{
    protected T _model;

    public S Stats { get { return _model.Stats; } set { _model.Stats = value; } }

}
```

and an interface:

```
public interface IStructure
{
    StructureStats Stats{ get; set;}
}
```

The code fails to compile, with the message

> Error 28  'Server.Models.Structures.Structure' does not implement interface member 'Server.Models.Structures.IStructure.Stats'. 'Server.Models.Structures.Structure.Stats' cannot implement 'Server.Models.Structures.IStructure.Stats' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Server.Models.Structures.StructureStats'. C:\SRDevGit\freecon-galactic-server\SRServer\Server.Models\Structures\Structure.cs

I am unsure as to what the problem is; the return type of Structure.Stats {get;} should be guaranteed to match the interface definition, since generic type S is defined as deriving from StructureStats by

```
where S:StructureStats, new()
```

What am I missing? I would like to avoid making IStructure generic, if possible, as it would complicate collections of

```
<IStructure<GenericType>>
```

because GenericType is a polymorphic class.

Comment: C# does not support return type variance.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? This approach seems convoluted at best.

Comment: I am attempting to avoid casting. Structure, StructureModel, and StructureStats are all polymorphic classes, however they are constrained such that a particular derived Structure must go with a specific derived StructureModel and a specific derived StructureStats. The major difficulty comes from the choice to separate object data into its own class (StructureModel), similar to the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# <s>is strongly typed, and</s> does not support covariant return types, so to inherit from IStructure, Structure has to return the exact signature `StructureStats Stats{ get; set;}`. Something like `StructureStatsDerived Stats{ get; set;}` is not an exact match and the compiler rejects it.

It looks like you don't actually need the generic parameter S. You could drop the S and just return StructureStats.

Comment: Note: the fact C# is strongly typed does not play big role here (one could support return value variation in strongly typed language)... It's the fact C# chose to require exact match as said in the rest of the answer.

Comment: @Alexei I agree, it's not a prerequisite of a strongly type language to require exact signature matches down an inheritance hierarchy, but this rule is more logical in a strongly typed language than it would be in a weakly typed language. That was why I thought it worth mentioning. Still, good point. I changed 'so' to 'and'.

Comment: I see. Following PetSerAl's comment, a quick search leads me to the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type, which indicates that this is a design choice inherent to C#. I've edited the answer to include the terminology. Thank you very much.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could anyone please elaborate as to why C# does not support covariant return types?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to achieve it without use a generic interface, also you need to switch the order in generic constraints for `Structure<T, S>`

```cs
public class Structure< T, S> : IStructure<S>
where S : StructureStats, new()
where T : StructureModel<S>, new()
{
    protected T _model;

    public S Stats { get { return _model.Stats; } set { _model.Stats = value; } }

}

public interface IStructure<S> where S : StructureStats
{
    S Stats { get; set; }
}
```